# microk8s is not running. use microk8s inspect for a deeper inspection

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, microk8s

After restarting the VM, microk8s stopped running.

```
Executing this command outputs the following:
microk8s status:
microk8s is not running. use microk8s inspect for a deeper inspection.
microk8s kubectl get pod:
The connection to the server 127.0.0.1 16443 was refused did you specify the right host or port?
```

I have practically tried all the methods, but there is no result.

Answer (score 3):

Run *ps -ef | grep kubelet*

Output will be somewhat like this:

*root       934     1  5 08:17 ?        00:20:40 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=**/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf** --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --network-plugin=cni --pod-infra-container-image=k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2*

Look for path of *kubelet.conf* and then edit port in that file. On this port, kubelet connects with kube-apiserver. Once it's fixed, output of *kubectl cluster-info* should be somewhat like this:

*Kubernetes control plane is running at https://192.168.56.2:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://192.168.56.2:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.*

Comment: I changed the port, it still refers to 16443. When running the command: microk8s kubectl get pods: Connection to server 127.0.0.1 16443 was rejected did you specify the correct host or port?

Comment: After making the changes, you need to restart the kubelet.                                                   
   `systemctl daemon-reload`                                                                                                               
  `systemctl restart kubelet`

Comment: Also you need to restart kubelets on all the nodes - master and worker nodes. For worker nodes, you need to ssh into them.

Answer (score 2):

Here the port is incorrect. It should be 6443 and not 16443. You can correct the port on master node in */etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf* file.

Comment: The answer is this : bash: /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf : No such file or directory

Comment: ok, but where your kubecofig is? how you installed cluster?